# Rewriting a download URL, but "save -as" dialog shows original URL

Tags: mod-rewrite, rewrite, lighttpd

I have the following `mod_rewrite` directive in my *lighttpd* config file:

```
url.rewrite-once = (
  "foo.*$" => "static/foo.pdf",
)
```

I'd like to hand out URLs like this: `http://<server>/foo/r=ca2b912` (or similar), such that I can track the origin of the link in the http access log.

When I enter `http://<server>/foo/r=131ab42`, however, the "save-as" file dialog is shown and is proposing to name the file `r=131ab42` (at least when using firefox). I'd like to have it propose `foo.pdf` as file name to save. This should work independent of the tool accessing the URL (ie. wget, IE, etc should all save the file as `foo.pdf`).

How can I achieve that? I've noticed that firefox corrects the file name when reloading the URL.

*Please note*: this is the first time I want to use a rewrite rule. I have tried to find the answer myself, but have not succeeded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to prefix your `r=ca92b32` string with a `?` (ie: `http://<server>/foo/?r=ca93b32`)

The string will be considered as a parameter instead of a filename and won't be treated as a filename.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tested your suggestions, but the string `&r=ca92b32` is not thrown away as you say. Files are then saved as `&r=ca92b32`.

Comment: You need to use a question mark, not an ampersand alone :)

Comment: my bad, thanks! The following works! `http://<server>/foo.pdf?r=sasdfasdf`. File is saved as `foo.pdf`

Answer (score 2):

rewrite is a server internal operation; the user doesn't see the result (unless you expose it manually in some way).

You could try the [Content-Disposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Disposition) header; but the best way is to fix your URLs (i.e. have `.../foo.pdf` from the beginning). You could use redirect rules for the migration.

Comment: you are right: `http://<server>/r=ca2b912/foo.pdf` works. Simple as that. This is an acceptable workaround for me. I also looked at your link, but that seems too complicated for my case.

Comment: I'll wait a couple of days with accepting in order to encourage other answers. Will accept if no other answers trickle in. Thanks.